# Ajax Grid field grouping

Tags: php, asp.net, javascript, ajax, user-interface

I research modern Ajax Grids capable of **grouping rows by fields** (into collapsible sections), in a manner similar to [ExtJs Grid grouping](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/grouping.html).

Important requirements to such a grid is not only grouping, but sorting by multiple fields, e.g. by country and gender. Ideally user needs to be able to select fields to group by (sort by) dynamically. I don't expect grids to do it, but knowing that given Ajax grid at least allows to build such a feature would be good.

Such a grid exists in ASP.Net world - http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GroupingSorting/Grouping.aspx - see it allows dynamic grouping by dragging required columns to upper bar. But as **PHP** developer I am not sure such thing exists as pure js-lib or as some PHP library.

What are other grids, except ExtJs grid, that support flexible/nested/dynamic field grouping, for using it in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqgrid does! I use it for adjacency lists and nested sets.. you can also do the whole expanding thing too:

http://trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

1. (click Advanced => Subgrid)
2. (click New in version 3.4 => Tree Grid Adjacency model)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use Tree Grid Adjacency model to represent a tree in jqgrid.